# Can XCode 3.2 run on 10.5 Leopard?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

Can XCode 3.2 run on 10.5.x Leopard? Or will it only work with Snow Leopard (10.6)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no, at least using the provided installer. The installer reports 10.6 is not found on any of my volumes and refuses to install.

Comment: No. Even if you managed to copy it onto a 10.5 machine by hand, it would refuse to launch, as it depends on Snow Leopard.

Comment: What happens if you change the reported system version to 10.6? A lot of the time Apple's OS retrictions are "name-only" checks and the applications don't actually require a particular version to run.

Comment: It won't work.  Xcode 3.2 is built using many Snow Leopard only APIs.  It is optimized for Snow Leopard through and through.  (Not sure where you got the "name-only check" impression... that just ain't true)

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 works on Windows XP, released 9 years before. However with Apple you need to surrender your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

NO, it doesn't work. It needs snow leopord to install.

Answer (score -3):

Snow Leopard [is just $25 for 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001AMHWP8) or [$49 for 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001AMPP0W)

Comment: We know how much it costs, but this is a horrible excuse for development software not to work. I used to be an Apple fan, but they have been grating on my nerves. Why should I need to upgrade my desktop OS if I want to develop for iOS? The two have nothing to do with each other: The iOS test environment runs in an emulator. And on top of that, having to pay $99 for the "privilege" of testing an app on physical hardware is just nonsense.