# Xcode 3.2.2 and iPhone SDK 3.2 on Leopard?

Tags: iphone, macos

Just a quick question of concern- the latest xcode and iphone sdk states 'Snow Leopard' beside it. Being new to Mac, does installing this on Leopard work? Please don't tell me to upgrade, I just want an answer.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399825/can-xcode-3-2-run-on-10-5-leopard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; Xcode 3.2 and iPhone SDK 3.2 both require Snow Leopard.