# install Xcode 3.2 for Mac OS 10.5.6?

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

i have a old mac  10.5.6 installed ...Since it is a P**owerPC G4** i cannot upgrade it to snow leopard now i am not able to find it anywhere will **XCode version 3.2 work on Mac OS 10.5 or not**??
also it has a Xcode 3.1.2 installed already in which when i try to create a new project only Mac applications bar appears and no option to build for IOS is present???

Comment: Welcome in apple's world ! Evolving fast and let old schools in the dark !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Xcode 3.2 is a revision of the Xcode toolset. It is available only with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and does not run on previous versions of Mac OS X.

[Xcode Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-DontLinkElementID_20)

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked before:

[Can XCode 3.2 run on 10.5 Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399825/can-xcode-3-2-run-on-10-5-leopard)

> It won't work. Xcode 3.2 is built
>   using many Snow Leopard only APIs.

so no it doesn't work