# installing xcode 3.2 and ios sdk 4.2 on imac 10.5 leopard

Tags: xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can XCode 3.2 run on 10.5 Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399825/can-xcode-3-2-run-on-10-5-leopard)

hi everyone 
i am having problem with my imac ... i installed 10.5 on my imac and the new xcode 3.2 and ios sdk 2.2 only work on snow leopard ... is it possible to use xcode 3.2 and ios sdk 4.2 on leopard 10.5 ??

thanks in advance

Comment: You just need upgrade your OS to Snow Leopard (10.6.x) first, and then install Xcode 3.2.x

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this isn't possible. The installer will refuse to run without detecting a Snow Leopard installation.