# How to build the install_name_tool manually on osx10.5?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I have an old Mac laptop(10.5) with XCode3.1 installed. The install_name_tool which was installed by Xcode3.1 has only two options, and doesn't support the 'add_rpath' option, but I really need it.

I've tried to install Xcode3.2, but it couldn't install ( it's also discussed here [Can XCode 3.2 run on 10.5 Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399825/can-xcode-3-2-run-on-10-5-leopard)). So I'm thinking if **is there any way to compile a newer version of install_name_tool manually?**

I found the source code in the cctools project, but I didn't find any instruction to how to build it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply with make in the `cctools` directory:

`make RC_MAJOR_RELEASE_TRAIN=Leopard`

`install_name_tool` will be in the "`misc`" directory